# jQuery appending multiple line string

Tags: jquery, html, string, append

I'm trying to append a string to a HTML element. It works fine when it's a one line string, but when I try to break it apart it stops working.

```
  <div><h4 >List to do:</h4><span id="added"></span></div>
```

This doesn't work:

```
  var addtext = "<ol>
                 <li>Item1</li>
                 <li>Item2</li>
                 </ol>"


                 $("span#added").html(addtext);
```

Can anyone help to make it work. I want to add a lot of HTML code, and I'd like it to be readable?

Answer (score 10):

try this :

```
var addtext = "<ol>\
                 <li>Item1</li>\
                 <li>Item2</li>\
                 </ol>";
```

Comment: Yes it works now. Thank you. So I need to escape a <CR>? Didn't know that.

Answer (score -2):

```
var addtext = '<ol><li>Item1</li><li>Item2</li></ol>';
```

Comment: It is not multiline string.